# how to run async batch job in batch-int:job-launching-gateway?

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-integration

Firstly thanks for attention,

I combined spring integration and spring batch in my project, i want to launch jobs in asynchronous mode in `batch-int:job-launching-gateway`, my means is that each message in input channel launch job in asynchronous and not wait util to complete the jobs,my code is:

```
 <batch-int:job-launching-gateway request-channel="outboundJobRequestChannel"
                                     reply-channel="jobLaunchReplyChannel"/>
```

**Update:**

Thanks for @Nenad for help me, i defined `JobRepository` and `JobLauncher` in my configuration as bellow code :

```
@Bean
    public MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean jobRepositoryFactoryBean() {
        MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean fb = new MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean();
        return fb;
    }
 @Bean
    public JobLauncher jobLauncher() throws Exception {
        final SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
        jobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepositoryFactoryBean().getObject());
        final SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor simpleAsyncTaskExecutor = new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor();
        jobLauncher.setTaskExecutor(simpleAsyncTaskExecutor);
        return jobLauncher;
    }
```

but not worked ,and thrown bellow exception:

```
Exception in thread "SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-20" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.MapJobExecutionDao.synchronizeStatus(MapJobExecutionDao.java:158)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.update(SimpleJobRepository.java:161)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor15.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy18.update(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor15.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:127)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy18.update(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:351)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:135)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be easier to simply change `outboundJobRequestChannel` to an `ExecutorChannel`. See [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#executor-channel) and [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#channel-configuration-executorchannel).

Comment: thanks for reply @Gary , it's worked correctly.how to create async router? my means is parallel routing

Comment: You can make any channel in your flow an `ExecutorChannel` to change a flow to async.

Answer (score 3):

`JobLaunchingMessageHandler` is using `JobLauncher` to launch jobs upon receiving `JobLaunchRequest`. You can define in configuration your `JobLauncher` as:

```
@Bean
public JobLauncher jobLauncher() {
    final SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
    jobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
    final SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor simpleAsyncTaskExecutor = new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor();
    jobLauncher.setTaskExecutor(simpleAsyncTaskExecutor);
    return jobLauncher;
 }
```

And that job launcher will be injected and used for launching jobs which will result in async launching.

Comment: thanks for fast reply @Nenad, how to set job Repository? or create  job Repository in my configuration?

Comment: If you have `@EnableBatchProcessing` you can just `@Autowired` it, if you are using spring boot. If not this might help you https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2013/06/spring-batch-2-2-javaconfig-part-3-profiles-and-environments/